# Ramanujan's False Claims

Tags: reference-request, math-history, big-list

> "During his short life, Ramanujan independently compiled nearly 3900 results (mostly identities and equations). Nearly all his claims have now been proven correct, **although a small number of these results were actually false** and some were already known." [(Source)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Srinivasa_Ramanujan)

What are some of Ramanujan's false claims?

---

Note: A long time ago, I remember reading a Hardy quote saying something to the effect that *where Ramanujan was wrong, he was likely right in some "deeper" sense.* I assume this was referring to claims such as

$$1+2+3+4+⋯=-\frac{1}{12}$$

I do *not* consider this statement a "false claim", but rather an imprecise way of saying that the analytic continuation of the zeta function evaluates to $-1/12$ at $-1$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When Ramanujan contacted Hardy he thought that he could provide a (nearly) exact formula for $\pi(n)$ the [prime counting function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function). This formula implicitely supposed that $\zeta$ had no complex zero at all! This is neatly detailed by Hardy at the beginning of his book ["Ramanujan"](http://www.amazon.fr/Ramanujan-Twelve-Lectures-Subjects-Suggested/dp/0821820230). See too Berndt's ["Ramanujan and the theory of prime numbers"](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/BFb0086402) for some details.

Comment: Berndt's ["Ramanujan and the theory of prime numbers" paper](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Number_Theory_Madras_1987/AIl8CwAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=Ramanujan+and+the+theory+of+prime+numbers&pg=PA122&printsec=frontcover)